# Counter example: Sobolev embedding

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces, laplacian

We know that $H^1(\mathbb{R^2})$ is not embedded in $L^\infty(\mathbb{R^2})$. Using the fact that $u \in H^2(\mathbb{R^4})$ if and only if $u, \Delta u \in L^2(\mathbb{R^4})$, how can I find a radial counter example of the fact that $H^2(\mathbb{R^4})$ is not embedded in $L^\infty(\mathbb{R^4})$?

Comment: The first counterexample I'm referring to is the following: let be $\psi$ a test function that is 1 on the ball $B(0,\frac{1}{2})$ and 0 out of the ball $B(0, \frac{3}{4})$. Consider $0 < \alpha < \frac{1}{2}$ and define u as $u(x) := (-\log (x))^{\alpha} \psi (x)$.